# Basic Java program: NoSuchElementException

Tags: nosuchelementexception

The problem is to rotate a number:

> You are given two numbers n and k. You are required to rotate n, k times to the right.

What is causing the `NoSuchElementException`?

```
import java.util.*;
   
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scn.nextInt();
    int k = scn.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      int p = n % 10;
      n = n / 10;
      int count = 0;
      while (n != 0) {
        count++;
        n=n/10;
      }
      int no = (p*(int)Math.pow(10,count)) + n;
      System.out.println(no);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you expect answers, you must learn how to edit reasonable markdown.  This is unreadable. I'll try to edit it.

Comment: nb: This problem is much more simply solved by converting the number to a string and rotating that.  Something like `String d = String.valueOf(n);  int m = d.length() - k; System.out.println(d.substring(m, d.length()) + d.substring(0, m));`